# convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(\pi /2-\arctan(\log n )) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like some help with the convergence of $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(\pi /2-\arctan(\log n)) $$ 
It conditionally converges since $$ (\pi/2-
\arctan(\log n)) \to 0 $$ as $n\to \infty$ 
and the derivative of the function $$(\pi/2-\arctan(
\log x)) $$ is $$-\frac{1}{x(\log^{2}x+1)}$$ so  the sequence is decreasing.By leibniz rule the sum conditionally converges, if I am not wrong.But i would like some help about the absolute convergence of the series.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28pi%2F2-arctan%28log%28n%29%29%29+n+from+1+to+inf) says it diverges if we remove the sign, and that it uses comparison test, but I don't know which comparison it makes. But the alternating series clearly converges conditionally, as you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac\pi2-\arctan x=\arctan \frac1x=\frac1x+O(x^{-3})$$
as $x\to\infty$. For absolute convergence you need to determine
if
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log n}$$
converges.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x>0$,
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
(the derivative of the left-hand side is zero).
Hence, for $n>1$
$$a_n:=(\pi /2-\arctan(\log n))=\arctan(1/\log n))\sim \frac{1}{\log(n)}\geq \frac{1}{n}$$
(note that $\arctan(x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$).
Therefore the series $\sum a_n$ is divergent.

Note that $a_n$ is positive and decreasing to zero ($\arctan$ and $\log$ are increasing functions), which implies that the series $\sum(-1)^n a_n$ is convergent by Leibniz's criterion.